# SharePoint 2013 and Sitecore 8.2 sharing the same Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint, sitecore

Is it applicable to have both SharePoint 2013 and Sitecore 8.2 installed on the same servers (sharing the same Infrastructure)? If yes, is there any drawbacks?

Thanks for your appreciated help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking it is safe, but both will make usage of IIS infrastructure to deliver their websites, and the machine hosting will take its toll on memory and possibly disk I/O depending on how any of these products were configured to store their data.

I had the unfortunate "pleasure" to work with Sitecore 7 and 8, and I can guarantee you it is possible and somewhat safe, but there are conditions to meet, let me go over some possible red flags here and it will hopefully help you to make a more balanced decision on how to set up both products on the same infrastructure.

**The first scenario and the safest: 3 SERVERS**

- SQL Server with two instances, segregating SharePoint and Sitecore
- One server for SharePoint (assuming it is a single farm server)
- One server for Sitecore (assuming you can handle search/indexing altogether)

This is the best and the safest, since IIS is the tug of war if both SharePoint and Sitecore reside on the same server, on the scenario above SQL Server can deal with both on the same instance if you don't mind access restrictions/security, but it is better to go on distinctive instances, will be safer and easier to administer

**The second scenario: 2 SERVERS**

- SQL Server with two instances, segregating SharePoint and Sitecore
- One server for SP + Sitecore

Yes you can have both but you will need to configure ports, sites, application pools and hardware requirements very carefully.

**Some considerations:**

Microsoft has made clear how SharePoint should be configured, you need a dedicated machine for SQL Server, anddifferent SharePoint servers according to their specific roles in a farm: Web Front End, Application Server, Search Server, etc. or if it is a very small "farm", you can cram all of them into one server but the SQL Server (this is where disk I/O is the king of the hill).

While Sitecore doesn't not need a farm like SharePoint it shares the same similarity, a dedicated server for SQL Server, one server for Sitecore and in some cases you will like to have another server for Search and Indexing.

The bottom line here is, all depends on how big is your project, and size here is measured in the number of factors: number of users, simultaneous users, volume of data stored.

I would not mix SharePoint and Sitecore on the same machine but I would not mind at all to mix them in the same SQL Server in different instances, the reason is simple, SharePoint is more likely to take a hold of IIS, assuming you are running SP 2010/2013, the User Profile Service and the FIM are a common cause of trouble in the SharePoint realm, and it is common for SP Admin to perform `IISRESET -NOFORCE` to troubleshoot cases like these.

If you are using Sitecore + MVC or MMVC, you might end up customizing the IIS Sites with some heavy loads and you will need to beef up the machine to not bring SharePoint down (assuming the SharePoint Central Admin and SharePoint Web Services + additional User Web Applications you have created) are all there installed on the same server.

I'm trying to not make this overly complicated but sharing some real world scenarios because it all boils down to the load on the server, you need to remember one thing, SharePoint is a beast and it is the one that will need more resources if you want a Single SharePoint Server +  Sitecore living on the same place, got it?

The recommendation from both Microsoft and Sitecore is clear: dedicated servers, and anything beyond this is at your own risk.

I've mixed and placed both together, it worked for me but I wouldn't do this again, it is not worth if have the chance to keep them apart.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dr. Sushi on all his points. One other thing to consider is the Sitecore licensing limitations. If you are using a persistent license (a.k.a. server license) most of them limit you to 8 cores on the server. If you are running both Sitecore and Sharepoint on the same server you might need to go beyond 8 cores to handle production load, which means now you have to buy multiple licenses for Sitecore for that single installation, or you have to switch to a subscription licensing model.